# WSO2 ESB clustering - sharing registry

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have tried to implement shared registry between clustered environment ESB 4.6.0 using GREG 4.5.3 following the guidance provided in provided in the [documentation](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Config+and+Governance+Partitions+in+a+Remote+Registry).
When I use the h2 db for currentDBConfig and the mysql database for mounted registry, WSO2 workers displays the following error when Deployment Synchronizer is automatically invoked:

```
Error while updating artifacts in the file system from the registry  {org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.registry.RegistryBasedArtifactRepository}
org.wso2.carbon.registry.synchronization.SynchronizationException: message code: ERROR_IN_READING_STREAM_TO_CREATE_META_FILE
```

When pointing currentDBConfig to the mysql database, the deployment synchronizer works ok and replicates configuration as expected, but according to the documentation it is not good practice.
How does the Deployment Synchronizer utilize the registry to update artifacts?

I have noticed that the User database uses by default the h2 database. Should it not be re-pointed to the shared governance registry database instead?

Thanks. Guillaume